# Bad image size on only some images when using bb argument of \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, bounding-box

I've had a snippet of code, that I've used (apparently) with `tex4ht` (which compiles with `latex`) to obtain an html document - and as far as I can remember (was some time ago) it worked without a problem. Now I try to compile the same snippet with `pdflatex`, and I have an erroneous image size - but this occurs only at some uses of the `bb=` (bounding box) parameter.

Apparently, I've needed to add the `bb=` parameter to avoid having separate bbox files when `latex` was to process this code, and AFAICR it worked fine. The thing is, I'd like to keep the same code also in the `pdflatex` compilation run.

For this, I've made a zip containing the original source images:

- [testpics.zip](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/9oIbNoD2/0/blob?download)

... and I've managed to reconstruct the error with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 1408 1056,width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG1.JPG}  \includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG2.jpg} %bb=0 0 1629 1221
\ifdefined\ifHtml\HCode{<br/>}\else\fi
\caption{Left: some text here; right: some text there}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 1000 1415,width=0.49\textwidth,trim=90 540 250 380,clip]{IMG3} \includegraphics[bb=0 0 1600 1200,width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG4}
\ifdefined\ifHtml\HCode{<br/>}\else\fi
\caption{Left: some text here; right: some text there}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is this (click for high res):

[image: test.png]

This is the problem:

- In the first figure (top two images), whenever I use the `bb=` parameter to `\includegraphics`, I get the wrong image size (much smaller than `width=0.49\textwidth`)
- In the second figure (bottom two images), I use the `bb=` paramaeter to `\includegraphics` - and here there is *no* problem, the size is *correct*?!

The IMG* images are originally from a camera; I replaced their contents with red fill in Gimp, and resaved - and strangely, the error still occurs; it is these image that are in [testpics.zip](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/9oIbNoD2/0/blob?download). So even if the image data itself is gone, EXIF data is still present in these images, and I tried:

```
exiftool -f IMG*
```

... but I cannot see anything strange about the first two images, which might cause this error when `bb=` is used in the first figure. Here is a quick overview of the image sizes:

```
$ identify IMG*
IMG1.JPG    JPEG 1408x1056 1408x1056+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 13KB 0.010u 0:00.000
IMG2.jpg[1] JPEG 1629x1221 1629x1221+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 16.1KB 0.000u 0:00.000
IMG3.jpg[2] JPEG 1000x1415 1000x1415+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 8.7KB 0.010u 0:00.000
IMG4.JPG[3] JPEG 1600x1200 1600x1200+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 15.6KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

But note what pdflatex outputs in the log when compiling:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 8.

<IMG1.JPG, id=1, 565.312pt x 423.984pt> <use IMG1.JPG>
<IMG2.jpg, id=2, 654.0435pt x 490.2315pt> <use IMG2.jpg>

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 16.

<IMG3.jpg, id=3, 1003.75pt x 1420.30624pt> <use IMG3.jpg>

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def)                using `viewport' instead on input line 16.

<IMG4.JPG, id=5, 1606.0pt x 1204.5pt> <use IMG4.JPG>
```

So, it sort of "interprets" the first two images to be smaller, but I really don't understand why.

Can anyone explain why this happens - and how could I get the code to compile correctly also in `pdflatex`, while keeping the original code with the `bb=` parameters in the `\includegraphics` command?

---

EDIT: Found out why the first two images are intepreted differently - they have a different print size/resolution:

```
$ identify -verbose IMG* | grep 'Image:\|Resolution:\|Print'
Image: IMG1.JPG
  Resolution: 180x180
  Print size: 7.82222x5.86667
    exif:FocalPlaneXResolution: 2816000/225
    exif:FocalPlaneYResolution: 2112000/169
    exif:XResolution: 180/1
    exif:YResolution: 180/1
Image: IMG2.jpg
  Resolution: 180x180
  Print size: 9.05x6.78333
    exif:FocalPlaneXResolution: 2816000/225
    exif:FocalPlaneYResolution: 2112000/169
    exif:XResolution: 180/1
    exif:YResolution: 180/1
Image: IMG3.jpg
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 13.8889x19.6528
Image: IMG4.JPG
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 22.2222x16.6667
    exif:FocalPlaneXResolution: 1600000/225
    exif:FocalPlaneYResolution: 1200000/169
    exif:XResolution: 72/1
    exif:YResolution: 72/1
```

So, apparently, those with resolution of 72 dpi have their `bb=` interpreted correctly, but those that do not have that print resolution (the first two are 180 dpi) have a bad size when `bb=` is used with `pdflatex`.

I guess I could just change the DPI print resolution of the images in Gimp and be done with it - but assuming I don't want to change neither the images nor the code, how would I proceed? I tried `texdoc graphicx`, but it doesn't seem to have a `resolution` parameter...

Answer (score 2):

If you need bb parameters, you have to give correct values.

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 1408 1056,width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG1.JPG}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG2.jpg} %bb=0 0 1629 1221
```

should be changed into

```
\includegraphics[bb=0 0 563 422,width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG1.JPG}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{IMG2.jpg} %bb=0 0 652 488
```

A command

```
extractbb IMG1.JPG
```

may tell you a correct boundingbox in a created IMG1.xbb.